# Hyper-parameter Optimisation in Cpp?

Tags: python, c++, neural-network, deep-learning

I need to fit a deep neural network to data coming from a data generating process, think of an AR(5). So I have five features per observation and one y for some large number N observations  in each simulation. I am interested only in the root mean squared error of the best performing DNN in each simulation.

Since it's a simulation setting, I have to do a large number of these simulations and within each simulation fit a neural network to the data. The only reasonable way I can think of doing this is fit the DNN via hyper-parameter optimisation given each simulation (dlib's find_min_global will be my optimiser).

Does it make sense to do this exercise in C++ (slow development because I am not proficient) or Python (faster iteration because I am fairly proficient).

From where I am sitting, C++ or Python might not make much of a difference in execution time, because the model has to be compiled each time the optimiser proposes a new hyper-parameter vector (am I wrong here?).
If it is possible to compile once, and test all hyper-parameters between the lower and upper bounds, then C++ would be my go to solution(Is this possible in any of the open source DNN languages?).

If anyone has done this exercise before, please advice.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

See looking at your problem, one way to implement this is to use genetic/evolutionary algorithm. Considering that I understood your problem correctly, you want to sweep through all the hyper-parameters to get the get the best solution.

[image]

So, I would recommend using python for this and tensorflow, keras all support this. So this might not be a problem. 
Note - If I understood your question differently, then please feel free to correct me.